# ¿Demasiado o demasiada?

Tags: adjetivos, género

Hoy leí una publicación en Facebook que mostraba un dialogo más o menos así:

> -A mi me gusta la luna, el café, los libros, escribir, la música y cantar.
>
> -Que raro eres
>
> -y tú demasiada común

A mi me sonó ese "demasiada" muy mal, así se hable de alguien femenino. Pienso que es "demasiado", pero no sé como explicarlo. La RAE presenta las entradas [demasiado/da](http://dle.rae.es/?id=C8sjljP) y es claro que "demasiada" es correcta en casos como "hay demasiada gente", pero siento que en el diálogo se usó de manera incorrecta.

¿Cuál es y cómo se explica la oración correcta en el ejemplo que doy?

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @guifa pero en la práctica es bastante común decirlo así: "Y tu eres demasiada común" (tal y como lo viste hoy). // Bueno, creo que ya te quedó claro, pero por las dudas, si la palabra describe un adjetivo, es adverbio.  Si describe una sustantivo, entonces es adjetivo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Trátase en este caso de un adverbio, porque *demasiado* modifica *común* y no *tú*.  Cuando *demasiado* es adverbio, es invariable y termina en *-o*, así que podemos decir que **aquella persona debió decir «y tú demasiado común»**

Comment: Es muy interesante. No recordaba que hubiese palabras que fueran adjetivos y también adverbios según el caso. Y con lo que me explicas ya aprendí a poner más atención al diccionario. Varias entradas decían "adv. indef." lo que imagino que es la "invariabilidad" que nombras.

Comment: @MauricioMartinez *indef.* significa que «indefinido», es decir, funciona como mucho o poco y representa una cantidad, pues, indefinida o inexacta, y por casualidad aquellas palabras flexionan de la misma forma.  En el latín, una forma de crear adverbios era usar la forma neutra del adjetivo y en algunos casos se ha mantenido esta forma en castellano (pero las formas neutra y masculina son iguales, cf. *demasiáu* [adj.m.] y *demasiao* [adj.n./adv] en asturiano)